# ModelBuilder Error 000354 Name contains invalid characters, using input selected from drop downs?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, error-000354

I've made a simple model in ModelBuilder, which is failing at the first step saying the name has invalid characters.

The failing tool is **Copy Features**:

[image]

The error is:

```
Executing (Copy Features): CopyFeatures "Geofabric Surface Network - V2.x\AHGFCatchment" in_memory\temp123 # 0 0 0
Start Time: Wed Mar 29 17:01:20 2017
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (Copy Features).
Failed at Wed Mar 29 17:01:20 2017 (Elapsed Time: 0.22 seconds)
```

[image]

The output name **in_memory\temp123** doesn't use any strange characters or bad words.

The input name was selected from the dropdown of layers available in the MXD:
[image]

The three 0 in the tool parameters are defaults and recommended by Arc.

I'm running this tool with some data selected from two layers - the purpose is to extract just the selected data to continue working on it.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Arc didn't like the group layer name containing a . in '2.x'.

Renaming the group layer in the list of layers in ArcMap (not renaming on disk or in Catalogue) allowed to the tool to run.

Answer (score 1):

From its documentation [Copy Features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm):

> Copies features from the input **feature class** or **layer** to a new feature class.

but you appear to be choosing a **layer file** instead.

Comment: I think this is from an open ArcMap session and the layer file is in a group layer in TOC.

Comment: @fatih_dur You are probably right - perhaps the asker can edit their question to include the properties that they have set on that parameter.